# Handle.exe does not unlock

Tags: windows, electron

I am running handle.exe to unlock files that are holding in a designated folder in electron app. When I do it in a development mode "npm start" it is working yet, when I "npm run build" and run the compiled exe I get "handle is invalid error".

The folder is created by the electron itself and at the end of the app the folder needs to be deleted. I cannot kill all tasks that are holdin lock for the folder content because electron alse holds a lock. moreover, I if I avoid to kill electron then its lock prevents me to delete the folder.

I am running bat file like this given below (bat name is kill.bat and takes two parameters):

for /f "tokens=3,6 skip=5 delims=: " %%i in ('%~f1 -accepteula %~f2') do %~f1 -c %%j -y -p %%i

so the usage is given as: kill.bat handle.exe FOLDER_PATH

Even I build the app as admin handle.exe cannot perform the unlocking

Comment: Hard to tell without more details, but it sounds to me as though at least one handle *is* being closed, and that's what is causing the "handle is invalid" error, i.e., you've invalidated a handle that Electron, or perhaps your program, is depending on.  It would probably be more useful to describe why you are trying to delete the folder in question, and asking how to do so.  Using `handle.exe` is not a very sensible solution IMO.

Comment: Electron app is running on public pcs so the folder needs to be deleted no matter what. Do you have anything in your mind as an alternative solution or a module maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be that my computer needed windows updates. After I got the updates the problem vanished. Most probably the updates were wannacry updates.

If you encounter a problem such like this try to make your updates